# Call RegisterWaitForSingleObject from Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, ctypes

I'm trying to call RegisterWaitForSingleObject on a file handle in Python to check if there's data asynchronously. My understanding is that I can create a callback function in Python, pass it to RegisterWaiForSingleObject, and as soon as there's data to read, the callback function will be called.

Here's my current implementation:

```
def _decl(name, ret=None, args=(), module=kernel32):
    fn = getattr(module, name)
    fn.restype = ret
    fn.argtypes = args
    return fn


WAITORTIMERCALLBACK = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(
    None,  # return value: VOID
    ctypes.wintypes.LPVOID,  # PVOID   lpParameter
    ctypes.wintypes.BOOL  # BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired
)
new_wait_object = HANDLE()
RegisterWaitForSingleObject = _decl(
    "RegisterWaitForSingleObject", 
    BOOL,
    (ctypes.POINTER(HANDLE), HANDLE, WAITORTIMERCALLBACK, LPVOID, DWORD, DWORD)
)

def waitortimercallback(lp_parameter, timer_fired):
    print('Data available')

c_waitortimercallback = WAITORTIMERCALLBACK(waitortimercallback)

result = RegisterWaitForSingleObject(
    ctypes.byref(new_wait_object),  # phNewWaitObject
    overlapped.hEvent,  # hObject
    c_waitortimercallback,  # Callback
    None,  # Context
    timeout_mil,  # dwMilliseconds
    0,  # dwFlags
)
```

I'm not sure I've done everything (or anything) correctly. But I've had success previously with WaitForSingleObject. Unfortunately there are no examples on the internet for RegisterWaitForSingleObject and Python. I probably defined some types incorrectly.

When I run my code, RegisterWaitForSingleObject returns 1 (success), but as soon as data is written, I receive "Segmentation fault" error.

Would appreciate any input.

Comment: *segfault* is *Nix* specific, while the func is *Win* specific. You probably mean "Access violation". You should not paste "..." in your code, as the error might be there. Also, stuff like *\_decl*, *new\_wait\_object*, ... is missing. Take a look at [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have added the missing code. Did not include file opening logic and ReadFile implementation, because I am sure that they work properly. And I definitely get "Segmentation fault", maybe it has something to do with the fact that I'm running the code from Cygwin. Will try other ways to run it later.

Comment: What if when defining *WAITORTIMERCALLBACK*, the 2nd arg type would be `ctypes.c_ubyte`?

Comment: `BOOLEAN` is `unsigned char` while `BOOL` is `int` in [Windows Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog/windows-data-types).

Comment: I've tried ctypes.wintypes.BOOLEAN and ctypes.wintypes.BOOL, ctypes.c_ubytes, the result is always the same.

Comment: I've now tried to run it just from windows command line. As soon as I write something, the reader script fails with %errorlevel% 255.

Comment: Even if it doesn't fix your error, you should change *WAITORTIMERCALLBACK*'s last arg to `ctypes.wintypes.BOOLEAN`. The *errorlevel* doesn't tell me very much. How did you run the program before anyway?

Comment: I've changed it to ctypes.wintypes.BOOLEAN. I can confirm now: if I run in in cygwin, I get Segmentation fault, if I just use Windows Command prompt, only errorlevel is available.

Comment: Could you post the *mcve*?